# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available with PowerMock and EasyMock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, easymock

I have a test case using PowerMock to test on static method from Math, as

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { Math.class })
public class Test{
    @Test
        public void test2(){
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(Math.class);
            EasyMock.expect(Math.abs(-123)).andReturn(1);
            EasyMock.replay(Math.class);
            long returns = Math.abs(-123);
            EasyMock.verify(Math.class);
            org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(1,returns);
        }
}
```

My pom.xml looks as

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And I got error as

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:559)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:537)
```

This is the first time I'm using PowerMock, I just want to try to test static method, and I Choose Java Math class to test. I think I have done all the parts in the instructions from https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

What's wrong with my test case?

Comment: There is a comment in the doc about mocking system classes. You might need to follow https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockSystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing a lot of things here. First, EasyMock and Mockito are two different things. So are PowerMock (which is used with EasyMock) and PowerMockito (which is used with Mockito). I'll stick with EasyMock here.

From there, when using PowerMock, the create, replace and verify are done by PowerMock. The reason is that you are passing a class to it, not and Object. So EasyMock won't like that.

Here is the working code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { Math.class })
public class MathTest {

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        PowerMock.mockStatic(Math.class);
        EasyMock.expect(Math.abs(-123)).andReturn(1);
        PowerMock.replay(Math.class);
        long returns = Math.abs(-123);
        PowerMock.verify(Math.class);
        assertEquals(1, returns);
    }
}
```